# Power BI - Showing Top 5 records in Metrix Table but total should show for all records

Tags: powerbi

I have table with thousands of record. i want to create a table visual that will show top 5 records for each category. i created a measure to achieve this and i am getting the result exactly the same i am looking for but facing one issue there.

See below image where i am showing top 5 records for each category, but after each category i have total.

I don't want that total for top 5 records i am showing in the table instead i want the total of all the records which is there under each category.

How can i achieve that?

Measure I created is - Top 5 = RankX(AllSelected(table(Category), Table(account), table(name)),amount_measure,,,Dense)
for Top 5 measure i am putting the filter for top 5.

[image]

| Category | Account | Name | P% | amount | country | owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Food | A101 | AA11 | 10% | 105 | India | A |
| Food | A102 | AA12 | 20% | 120 | India | A |
| Food | A103 | AA13 | 80% | 100 | India | A |
| Food | A104 | AA14 | 30% | 150 | India | A |
| Food | A105 | AA15 | 60% | 90 | India | A |
| Stat | B101 | AA11 | 10% | 205 | India | A |
| Stat | B102 | AA12 | 20% | 220 | India | A |
| Stat | B103 | AA13 | 80% | 200 | India | A |
| Stat | B104 | AA14 | 30% | 250 | India | A |
| Stat | B105 | AA15 | 60% | 190 | India | A |
| Admn | D101 | AD11 | 10% | 305 | India | A |
| Admn | D102 | AD12 | 20% | 320 | India | A |
| Admn | D103 | AD13 | 80% | 300 | India | A |
| Admn | D104 | AD14 | 30% | 350 | India | A |
| Admn | D105 | AD15 | 60% | 290 | India | A |

Thanks,
SK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

Let's suppose you have the following measures

```
_sumAMT:= SUM('Table 1'[amount])
```

and this is your ranking measure

```
_sumAMTRank:= RANKX(ALLEXCEPT('Table 1','Table 1'[Category]),[_sumAMT],,DESC,Dense)
```

You can revise the subtotal by doing this

```
_sumAMT by CAT:= CALCULATE(SUM('Table 1'[amount]),ALLEXCEPT('Table 1','Table 1'[Category]))
_revisedTotal:= IF(HASONEVALUE('Table 1'[Name])=true(),[_sumAMT],[_sumAMT by CAT])
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Hi Smpa01, Thanks for your time and resolution, i think i was not clear about my issue hence i modified my question.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give a sample dataset not as a picture, by providing an actual sample table.

Comment: i dont think so there is a option to attach a file or paste data as table with question here

Comment: You need to paste sample markdown tables [how to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow).

Comment: Hi smpa01 - Thanks for sharing useful information. I got the success to update details in table format

Comment: smpa01 - i just updated 5 records for each category for sample. here we can experiment to show top 2 records with total of all 5 records for each category

Comment: Thank you smpa01 - This is exactly i am looking for. I learnt PBI completely through you tube videos and today came to know that there is lot more to learn.